# Razor modelItem Int to DayofWeek

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm doing a project in Asp.net Core 2.1 (EF, MVC, SQL Server) and simply trying to turn an `byte` (i.e. tinyint) (e.g. 1) into it's equivalent day of the week name (e.g. Monday) in my view. The default scaffolding comes out like this (DayId is the byte from 0 to 6 and is nothing more than a `public byte DayId {get; set;}` in my model):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayId)
```

Based on other SO questions, I've tried like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek),item.DayId))
```

this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), Convert.ToInt32(item.DayId))))
```

things the Intellisense clearly didn't approve of, like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayId.DayofWeek)
```

I'm mostly shooting in the dark. Is there an easy way to do this? Should it be done in the controller or model maybe?

I figured it would be an easy conversion and I could save a sql join, but it's not feeling easy at this point. Would it be better to just go back to my join table with seven rows in it? Thanks.

Comment: Why is you property not `DayOfWeek`instead on `int` if that is what it represents? And there is no reason to use `DisplayFor()`

Comment: I was not aware I could do that. So you mean in my model, `public DayOfWeek DayId {get; set;}`? And that would get my desired result in my view?

Comment: That would make more sense :) And you can just use `@Model.DayId.ToString()` in the view

Comment: Actually, I'm not correct above, I used `byte` instead `int`. I don't know if that matters or not? I'll correct that now...

Comment: Ok, let me try your suggestion... Thanks!

Comment: My model migration updated ok, but am finding myself in a new rabbit whole of razor errors (as I usually do). The DisplayFor was the default scaffolding and they also put my using statement as `@model IEnumerable<Stats.Models.Order>` I get rid of `IEnumerable` and then it's a issue with my default foreach statement (cannot operate on variables of type 'Order'). I seem to be having deja vu right now and will compare some of my past projects. However, I noticed that DayOfWeek property is int now vs the byte I had before. Isn't this costing me four bytes now instead of one?

Comment: Its insignificant compared to the benefits of strong typing to the `enum`:) I cannot comment on the other issues because you have not shown all the relevant code, but using `DisplayFor()` is a bit pointless (you do not have any formatting, or a `DsiplayTemplate`)

Comment: Hey, got sidetracked on this whole byte vs int thing... I got some changes to make there on other properties.... Anyway, your suggestion totally worked without changing anything but that `DayOfWeek` property. If I go back to the default `DisplayFor` syntax (`item.DayId`), it returns Monday for 1 and so on in my view... perfect. I'll ditch the `DisplayFor` coding later when I start down that rabbit *hole* (spelled it incorrect previously)... if you want to put up an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your property to represent an `enum` value for `DayOfWeek`, then your property should be `DayOfWeek`, not `int`, which gives you the benefit of strong typing

```
public DayOfWeek DayId { get; set; } // perhaps Day or DayOfWeek would be a better nane
```

Then in the view you can use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DayId)
```

or just

```
@item.DayId
```

since there is no real need for the extra overhead (albeit minor) of using `DisplayFor()` in this case.

Comment: Thanks again Stephen. I am going to change that (`join` remnant) `DayId` name too...